# ng-repeat in Angularjs is printing 3 times

Tags: angularjs

```
index.html
----------

<html ng-app="phoneAPP">
<head>

<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js"></script>

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="phoneListController">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="phone in phones">

{{phone.name}} : {{phone.snippet}}
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

Controller
-----------
var phoneApp = angular.module('phoneAPP',[]);
phoneApp.controller('phoneListController',function($scope)
{
$scope.phones =[{'name': 'Nexus s',
                 'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
                 {'name':'MOTOROLA',
                  'snippet': 'MOTORALA Brand is good'},
                 {'name': 'NOKIA',
                  'snippet': 'NOKIA Brand has been gone'}];

});
```

O/P
   •Nexus s : Fast just got faster with Nexus S. 
•Nexus s : Fast just got faster with Nexus S. 
•Nexus s : Fast just got faster with Nexus S. 
•MOTOROLA : MOTORALA Brand is good 
•MOTOROLA : MOTORALA Brand is good 
•MOTOROLA : MOTORALA Brand is good 
•NOKIA : NOKIA Brand has been gone 
•NOKIA : NOKIA Brand has been gone 
•NOKIA : NOKIA Brand has been gone

why it is printing 3-3 times if i want to print only once.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for it and share?

Comment: Why are you including angular.js and angular.min.js? just include one of them, and comment out the other.

Comment: why you include 3 times Angular script? try also use new version like 1.2.16 not ancient 1.0.x...

Comment: Ya after removing angular.min.js , now it is working fine. Thanks pixelbits

Comment: Plunkr with the sample working http://plnkr.co/edit/9ygMXq2o7fCfmbBFjLwi?p=preview, it was what Yoorek said.